# Replacing word with icon

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/"><div 
class="email"><span><center><span class=icon- 
email>EMAIL</span></center></span></div></a>
```

This displays the word EMAIL.

How can I replace that word with an envelope icon and have it work in mobile and desktop?

I tried:

```
&#x1F4CD
```

Which display email icon in mobile, but nothing in desktop.

Even tried fa fa-envelop, which just displays fa fa-envelope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use any of the icon library, for example [font awsome][1].

Also make sure that you need to add class within the quotes.

Using the font awesome, you can display email like this:

```
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/"><div 
class="email"><span><center><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></center></span></div></a>
```

Comment: Cool. Appears to have worked. But without EMAIL word. If you adjust I'll mark as correct. Thanks dude.

Comment: Wouldn't mind adjusting myself but perhaps not the honourable thing.

Comment: what you want to do is just remove the word email.thats it. see http://jsfiddle.net/f75ky8md/1/

Comment: When you've removed the word Email, i will

Comment: I removed word Email and marked as correct. Thanks for your time.